# Fun with Newton's Method - Infinitely many cycles

Tags: polynomials, dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems

I'd like to preface this problem by saying that I have absolutely no clue if it is solvable or not. This is just the result of some musings, and I'm looking for either some guidance, or to be pointed in the direction of a solution if one is known.

The goal is to find a function, hopefully a polynomial, but this is not a requirement, which contains infinitely many cycles in it when Newton's Method is applied to it. An example of such a cycle is a 2-cycle which arises in the function $f(x)=x^3-2x+2,$ along with the starting point $x=0$ as the starting point. Applying Newton's Method ($N(x)=x- \frac {p(x)}{p'(x)})$ to this yields $N(0)=0-\frac {2}{-2}=1$. Taking $1$ as the next point then gives. $N(1)=1-1=0,$ yielding the 2-cycle.

Now, I know that there exists an ordering of the natural numbers, so that the existence of some cycles implies the existence of other cycles, which, if I remember correctly, is called the Sarkovskii ordering. Since this ordering shows that $2 \rhd 1,$ there should be a fixed point to this function. In the context of Newton's Method, this should be somewhat obvious - that somewhere for $f(x)$ there shoudl be a point $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)=0$. A quick sketch of this function shows that there is such a point. However, the ordering says a good deal about the existence of these cycles, and in particular, that the existence of a 3-cycle implies the existence of a cycle of any other period.

Knowing this information, I'm seeking a function with a 3-cycle, so that all other periods exist as well. I have tried investigating this issue by hand, by seeking the period 3 points of the function $N(x)$ and hopefully noting some useful pattern but it's immediately clear to me that even $N^2(x)$ is quite difficult to work with (if $N^2(x)=N(N(x))$, that is). Since

$N^3(x)=N(N^2(x))=N((x- \frac {p(x)}{p'(x)})- \frac {p (x- \frac {p(x)}{p'(x)})} {p'(x-\frac {p(x)}{p'(x)})})$

So I'm hoping that someone knows another way to cook up a function which will behave like this. Or can at least point me in the right direction. Also, I don't know what tags to use properly for this question, so I tagged the same things I used when I was in an introductory course in dynamical systems.

Comment: Well, it is straightforward to construct a polynomial $p_n$ with an $n$-cycle on, say, $[0,1]$ **and** $p_n(0) = p_n(1) = 0$. Then let $f$ be $p_1$ on $[0,1]$, a shifted version of $p_2$ on $[1,2]$, etc. Then $f$ has an infinite number of cycles or arbitrary length.

Comment: Can you give an example? I'm not sure I understand. I'm looking for a polynomial which gives a 3-cycle under Newton's Method for some appropriate starting point, and I don't see how to get from here to there.

Comment: Sure. Find a polynomial that satisfies $p(0) = 1, p'(0) = -1$, $p(1) = 1, p'(1) = -1$ and $p(2) = 1, p'(2) = {1 \over 2}$. Basically you need $p'(x_n)(x_n-x_{n+1}) = p(x_n)$, so fix the $p(x_n) = 1$, the $x_n$ and then choose $p'(x_n)$ to suit.

Comment: Ah. I see now. If no one has posted an answer in the morning, I'll find a polynomial and put one up myself, or if you like, feel free to throw an answer there and I'll accept it in the morning.

Comment: Newton's Method is a function defined above which approximates successively the roots of a polynomial. However, sometimes, points get caught in loops and don't ever actually tend towards a 0 under his method. It is a known fact that cycles of certain lengths imply cycles of other lengths, and in particular, if there is a 3 cycle, then a cycle of any length can be found. The question is to cook up a function with such a 3 cycle when Newton's method is applied. That is to say that for some $x$, $N(N(N(x)))=x$

Comment: $p(x)=x^5-x-1$ is another such polynomial. Just compute the orbit of $N(x)=x-p(x)/p'(x) = x - (-1 - x + x^5)/(-1 + 5 x^4)$ starting at $x_0=0.0$ and you'll find an attractive three-cycle.

Comment: How did you find that polynomial? Similarly to copper.hat's answer or by some other method?

Comment: @AlfredYerger Honestly, the fact that $N$ has an attractive orbit of period 3 for $p(x)=x^5-x-1$ is a very random fact that I just happened to know! I describe in the answer I just posted a technique to find such polynomials, though. More - the answer provides polynomials of lowest possible degree that meet your specifications.

Comment: @AlfredYerger Incidently, I noticed your question only by happenstance. If you want folks to be pinged of your queries, be sure to prepend the "@" symbol to your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try $p(x) = (x−2)(x−1)x(−{9x^2 \over 8}+{21x \over 8}−{1 \over 2})+1$.

You have $p(0) = p(1) = p(2) = 1$ and $p'(0) = p'(1) = -1, p'(2) = {1 \over 2}$.

Using $x_{n+1} = x_n - { p(x_n) \over p'(x_n) }$ we find that with $x_0 = 0$, we get
$x_1 = 1, x_2 = 2, x_3 = 0,...$

Answer (score 7):

A general strategy to find functions with desired properties is to study a parametrized family of functions.  This is exactly the path to the bifurcation diagram in real dynamics and the Mandelbrot set in complex dynamics.

**A super-attractive orbit of period 3**

After a little experimentation, I decided to look at the family of cubic polynomials $f_{\lambda}(x)=\lambda+x-x^3$, which has the associated Newton's method iteration function 
$$n_{\lambda}(x)=\frac{2 x^3 + \lambda}{3 x^2-1}.$$
Note that 
$$n_{\lambda}'(x)=\frac{6 x \left(x^3-x-\lambda \right)}{\left(1-3 x^2\right)^2}$$
so that $x=0$ is a critical point.  Thus, to find a value of $\lambda$ so that $n_{\lambda}$ has a super-attractive orbit of period 3, it suffices to find a value of $\lambda$ such that $n_{\lambda}(n_{\lambda}(n_{\lambda}(0))) = 0$.  Grabbing just the numerator of the left hand side, this equation is equivalent to
$$-16 \lambda ^9+51 \lambda ^7-39 \lambda ^5+11 \lambda^3-\lambda = 0.$$
Using your favorite numerical solver, it turns out that $\lambda\approx -1.49175$ does the trick.

**A repulsive orbit of period 3**

If you stick to quadratic polynomials, you're not going to find any attractive orbits of period 3, but you can find repelling orbits of period 3.  Indeed, consider the polynomial $p(x)=x^2+1$.  This has no real roots so perhaps it's not surprising that the corresponding Newton's method iteration function
$$n(x)=\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{2 x}$$
displays chaotic behavior on the real line.  Thus, we might expect a point of period 3.  To find it, simply solve the equation $n(n(n(x))) = x$.  This is equivalent to
$$\frac{x^8-28 x^6+70 x^4-28 x^2+1}{8 x \left(x^6-7 x^4+7x^2-1\right)} = x.$$
Or using your favorite numerical solver again, you can find the roots.  There are six real roots forming two orbits of period 3 namely
$$2.07652 \rightarrow 0.797473 \rightarrow -0.228243 \rightarrow 2.07652$$
and
$$-2.07652 \rightarrow -0.797473 \rightarrow 0.228243 \rightarrow -2.07652.$$

Comment: Nice 1! I was thinking about this - "This has no real roots so perhaps it's not surprising that the corresponding Newton's method iteration function displays chaotic behaviour on the real line"? It des not have real roots then how can we talk about the dynamics on the real line and also if the roots are not real, how the Newton's methods displays chaotic behaviour? how can I think about this?

Comment: @BAYMAX Well, the attractive fixed points of a Newton's method function $N$ are exactly the roots of the original function $f$. So, if $f$ has no roots then we can be sure that (at least) no orbit converges to an attractive point. Thus, perhaps, it's not to hard to believe that an orbit might meander around instead.